# How to use thread in Android JAVA for DB Task

Tags: java, android, threadpool

what method to use when I want to create a new thread > run a DB task > return a result > run another task if DB Task was succeeded > then return to the main Thread to update UI using the received results?

I know that `Kotlin coroutine` is the solution to this in Kotlin, but how to achieve this in Java, and after the famous `AsyncTask` was deprecated?

++
I used [threading](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading) Documentation for some info, but the code was complex to understand, could be there a simple code to achieve the above use case mentioned for others' future reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to do it is by using [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) and [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid)

after you implement its libraries you can use `single` for 1 emit and `Observable` for multiple emits

e.g.

```
private Single<returnType> getSomthing() {
        return Single.create(emitter -> {
           //write the DB call you want ot make in background
            emitter.onSuccess(varToReturnOnSuccess);
        });
    }
```

a single will just return the one data you sent with `emitter.onSuccess`, and you will get it in subscribe like:

```
  .subscribe(returnedVar -> {
                    //use it here
                });
```

the final call will be like :

```
getSomthing()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(returnedVar -> /*use the returned var here*/ , throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace());
```

the `getSomthing()`, `returnedVar`,`returnType`, and `varToReturnOnSuccess` are names just for explanation only, and they can be changed accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```java
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private HandlerThread dbHandlerThread = null;
    private Handler dbHandler = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dbHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("db-thread");
        dbHandlerThread.start();
        dbHandler = new Handler(dbHandlerThread.getLooper());

        doSomeDbStatement();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (dbHandlerThread != null) {
            dbHandlerThread.quitSafely();
        }
    }

    private void bringResultHere(List<Data> result) {
        // do something here
    }

    private void doSomeDbStatement() {
        dbHandler.post(() -> {
            final List<Data> result = doFetchDataFromDb();
            
            MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> bringResultHere(result));
        });
    }
}
```